# Meaning of "to fall smack on her overextended haunches"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a tutorial on ballet classes, I came across the following sentence:

> Once a star is born, she is given every imaginable opportunity **to fall smack on her overextended haunches.**

I do not understand the meaning of the fragment in bold.

Comment: Was there one particular word that you didn't understand? There's nothing idiomatic here;  'haunches' is a rare term but you can look it up.

Comment: Hi Mitch, there wasn't a particular word I hadn't understood. I couldn't understand the meaning of the sentence, but I believe Gnawme gave the best answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a fancy of saying that a ballerina with star quality is given every opportunity to *fall on her ass*, or, to put it more directly, to fail.

The line is from an article in *[Time](http://content.time.com/time/subscriber/article/0,33009,919577,00.html)* (subscription required) titled "Dance: U.S. Ballet Soars." The relevant paragraph (emphasis mine):

> Countless thousands of little girl ducklings each year paddle into
>   this wrenching regimen, known politely as ballet class. Many are
>   shoved by doting mommies and daddies with an atavistic sense of how
>   young ladies are supposed to move. A single-minded few are driven by
>   the demonic notion that they could, some day, be swans. Most are
>   mistaken. Once in a great while though, the real thing comes along,
>   and word rapidly spreads through one of the world's oldest permanent
>   floating meritocracies. Leningrad hears it, and so do Stuttgart,
>   Covent Garden and New York: a star is born who might, just might, be
>   capable of being made. So recognized, this singular creature is then
>   *cosseted and punished, cradled from outside interruptions and given
>   every imaginable opportunity to fall smack on her overextended
>   haunches*. Meanwhile, the cognoscenti settle back for a long wait. A
>   verdict should be in in about ten years.

Comment: Good find. And I agree with you that this it means to *fall on her ass-  to fail*.  OP's claim that this came from a ballet tutorial is completely false.

Comment: @Jim There is no reason to say her claim is false. This is something that could easily be cited in a tutorial on (giving?) ballet classes.

Comment: Jim, I was given this as a tutorial, not as an article from Time

Answer (score 2):

Not being familiar with ballet, I would have to assume that a dancer must endeavor to keep their *haunches* (hips and buttocks) from being overextended during their dance lest they lose their balance and fall.  The narrator here is both stating that the dancer fell and smugly asserting that the reason she fell was that she was out of position.

Comment: I read "overextended" as a snide comment on the dancer's size, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @ColinFine- Interesting take.  I'm not sure I would go along with it given OP says this came from a ballet tutorial.

Comment: Hi again.
The narrator says: "...once a star is born, she is given every imaginable opportunity to fall smack on her overextended haunches."

Comment: In that case I think this is a play on words where on the surface it refers to the straight balancing/position problem I discuss above, but it is really a commentary on "her fame and fortune going to her head, and becoming *overextended* in the rest of her life off the stage and her coming crashing down in the public's eye when she is 'caught'

Comment: tks Jim, I agree with you

Comment: Not a very nice way to refer to a ballet dancer. Horses have haunches and sweat, young ladies have hips and glow.

Comment: I would interpret the ‘overextended’ bit to mean simply that ballet dancers very often get into poses where their hips and legs are in positions that the human body was not meant to withstand. When you’re doing 200° splits in the air with your back bent over backwards, your haunches are quite literally _overextended_.

Comment: @alex_brazil - you agree with me but you accepted a different answer?

Comment: Having known dancers, I would comment that their gluteus maximi do tend to become, shall we say, highly developed.

Comment: Yes, Jim, 'cause I think Gnawme's answer is better than yours. However, I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.